# FTP "get" file from directory

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

How I can use the ftp get file to specific directory?

For Example:

I can't do this (A):

```
ftp> get /var/apache/cgi-bin/test-cgi
local: ./var/apache/cgi-bin/test-cgi remote: /var/apache/cgi-bin/test-cgi
local: ./var/apache/cgi-bin/test-cgi: No such file or directory
```

I can do this (B):

```
ftp> cd /var/apache/cgi-bin/
ftp> get test-cgi
```

But :

I want directly get the file from directory (A)..

Please Help Me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ftp> get /some/path/some/file FreddyFrog
```

which will get `/some/path/some/file` and store it as `FreddyFrog` in your current local directory.

Or this:

```
ftp> get /some/path/some/file /local/path/filename
```

which will fetch the remote file and write it in `/local/path/filename`

Or you can do this:

```
ftp> cd /var/apache/cgi-bin
ftp> lcd /local/someplace
ftp> get test-cgi
```

which will change directory to `/var/apache/cgi-bin` on the remote machine, LOCALLY change directory to `/local/someplace` and then download `test-cgi` to your local directory you just set.

The reason your command doesn't work, is because by default, FTP tries to download the remote file to the same name in the local filesystem, so it found the file you wanted but couldn't download it because the directory `/var/apache/cgi-bin` does not exist on your local machine and you had not told it anywhere else to save the file - whereas I did - I told it to save the file as `FreddyFrog`.